# How to send the same message to multiple clients

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I just started playing around with azure and service bus.  I am trying to be able to send the same message to multiple clients.  In other messaging solutions if you have multiple clients listening to a topic and you send a message to a topic they all get the message.  With Azure only one of the subscribers gets the message.  I am sure I am missing something can anyone provide a pointer ?  My sample code is below.

```
string connectionString =
"Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=";
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
string topic = TestTopic.Replace("/", ".").Replace("{", "-").Replace("}", "-");
if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(topic))
{
var td = new TopicDescription(topic)
    {
    MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120,
    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    };

namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);
}


var message = new {CurrencyCode = "AUD", EffectiveDate = DateTime.Today, Rate = .97M};

TopicClient publisher = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topic);
var bm = new BrokeredMessage("fff");
bm.Properties["Topic"] = ".xxx.fxrates.aud";

int messagesReceived = 0;
int messagesReceived2 = 0;

if (namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topic, "test") == false)
{
SubscriptionDescription sub = namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topic, "test");
}

SubscriptionClient subscriber = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topic,
                                      "test",
                                      ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
SubscriptionClient subscriber2 = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topic,
                                       "test",
                                       ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
subscriber.OnMessage(delegate { messagesReceived++; });

subscriber2.OnMessage(delegate { messagesReceived2++; });

publisher.Send(bm);
namespaceManager.DeleteTopic(topic);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to uniquely name your subscribers! Currently your both subscribers are named "test". Second, you have to do ReceiveMode.PeekLock, but not ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete if you want other subscribers to also get the message.

I know we developers hate to RTFM, but when nothing else helps (including StackOverflow question) it is good idea to take a look at it (the Manual): [Service Bus Queues, Topics and Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh367516.aspx) is a good source for understanding how it works. And [How to use Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) will take you to the right point.

Comment: Each subscriber has its own queue, so it doesn't matter if each subscriber does PeekLock or ReceiveAndDelete, the other subscribers will get the message whether or not another subscription (queue) has already read the message or not.